# MySQL cascade delete on self-referencing parent-child table?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have this MySql database table:

```
tbl_project
id
project_name
parent_id
```

If a project is a 'parent', `parent_id` is `0`.

Now I'm trying to add a self referencing foreign key

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_tbl_project_tbl_project` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_project` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

When I try to insert a new record,

```
SQL Error (1452): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (mydbname.#sql-3539_d7d, CONSTRAINT FK_tbl_project_tbl_project FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES tbl_project (id) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Basically I just want all the children to be deleted when I delete the parent. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have a row in this table where `id=0`?

Comment: No. It starts with 1, because `id` is an auto-increment PK

Comment: So when you enter `0` into the `parent_id` column of a new row, the foreign key _requires_ that there is a row where `id=0`, because that's how foreign keys work. If you want to use a foreign key, you should use NULL instead of 0 for the `parent_id` of a row that has no parent to reference. Foreign keys ignore NULL.

Comment: @BillKarwin, that's it. I now converted `parent_id` `0`'s to `NULL`'s. Turn that into an answer, so I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter any value into the parent_id column of a new row, the foreign key requires that there is a row where id has that value, because that's how foreign keys work.

If you want to use a foreign key with your self-referencing relationship, you should use NULL instead of 0 for the `parent_id` of a row that has no parent to reference. Foreign keys ignore NULL.

Comment: looking back, would it be better/worse if I have the parent records have their `parent_id` reference their own `id` instead of being `NULL`?

Comment: Why not use NULL?